# Effects of Electron/Ion Particle Spray on Antennae

Tags: electrons

I was wondering if an antenna could pick up some sort of signal if it was exposed to a spray of electrons or ions.
For instance I have a patch antenna calibrated for 300 MHz. The patch antenna was placed in an environment where it could be getting sprayed by a wave of electrons followed by a wave of ions. In the antenna response I see a very strong signal voltage drop follow by a strong spike that is temporally correlated with when it would be getting sprayed, but the frequency of this signal is orders of magnitude below 300 MHz. Is this a possible effect of the particle spray, or is it more likely that something else is the cause of this low frequency signal showing up on a high frequency antenna.
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An antenna can pick up any kind of signal, regardless of what it was calibrated for. Only the quality and the intensity of the picked up signal varies a lot. If there is a signal far away from the calibrated range, its picked up intensity will be much lower if you have the same sent intensity.

If you now rise the intensity of the sprayed signal a lot - and the direct impact of a wave of electrons is a huge signal, I guess its some magnitudes more intense than any radio signal - it will give you a high impact on your antenna, even if it is far away from 300 MHz.

I think in any case it is a very bad idea to place a antenna in a place where it can be sprayed by electrons....